# Using Generic Type T in a class property

Tags: c#, generics

In c#, how would I go about setting up a class that can return another class (of any type).

For example:

```
public class DataResponse {

public bool Success {get;set;}
public string ResponseMessage {get;set;}
public T Data {get;set;}

}
```

T should be any type of class.

```
var personData = new PersonClass() {
           FirstName= "John",
           LastName="Doe"
          };


var response = new DataResponse<EmployeeClass>() {
Success = true;
ResponseMessage = "OK";
Data = personData
}
```

then I can go and get

```
response.Data.FirstName
```

The data proprety will be of a changing class it could be a person or an employer for example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your [class generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f.aspx):

```
public class DataResponse<T> // class is parametrized with T
{
    public bool Success {get;set;}
    public string ResponseMessage {get;set;}
    public T Data {get;set;}
}
```

Now your code will work - create class parametrized with some specific type and `Data` property will have that type:

```
var response = new DataResponse<EmployeeClass> {
                  Success = true;
                  ResponseMessage = "OK";
                  Data = personData
               };
```

**NOTE**: I like to create [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) which create response objects based on data I have:

```
public static DataResponse<T> ToSuccessResult<T>(this T data)
{
    return new DataResponse<T> {
                  Success = true;
                  ResponseMessage = "OK";
                  Data = data
               };
}
```

Now type of `T` can be inferred from your data type and response creation will look like:

```
var response = personData.ToSuccessResult();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the generic type parameter at the class level:

```
public class DataResponse<T> // <-- here
{
    public bool Success {get;set;}
    public string ResponseMessage {get;set;}
    public T Data {get;set;}
}
```

So now, as long as `EmployeeClass` has a property named `FirstName`, this will work:

```
var personData = new PersonClass() {
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe"
};

var response = new DataResponse<EmployeeClass>() {
    Success = true;
    ResponseMessage = "OK";
    Data = personData
};
Console.WriteLine(response.Data.FirstName); // John
```

Answer (score 2):

Only methods and types can be generic. Which means that you cannot declare a generic property. The best you can do is make the class that contains the property generic.

```
public class DataResponse<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your class generic, as suggested by Sergey Berezovskiy and p.s.w.g.  Additionally, you could require that T be of a type that implements FirstName and LastName:

```
public interface INamable
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class DataReponse<T> where T : INamable
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```